# heritage and overloaded function

Tags: c++, oop

Rather than a long explanation, I think a few lines of code will be clearer to explain my problem. Lets say I have 2 classes, one inheriting from the other :

```
#include <iostream>
class A{
    public: 
        void parse() 
        {
            treatLine();
        };
        void treatLine()
        {
            std::cout << "treatLine in A" << std::endl;
        }
};

class B : public A{
    public:
        void treatLine()
        {
            std::cout << "treatLine in B" << std::endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    b.parse();
    return 0;
}
```

When executing, surprisingly for me, it prints "treatLine in A". Is it possible to make function treatLine from class B to be called whith an object of type B (ie "treatLine in B" would be print for the code above)? And keep the possibility of creating an object of type A that would print "treatLine in A"

Comment: All `B`'s does is shadow `A`'s, not override it. You're missing a key word in there.

Comment: @chris B's method treatLine does override A's method, doesn't it ?

Comment: If it did, it would be overriding the call, don't you think? You need the `virtual` there (only required in the base class, optional in the derived class) to mark the function as one to be overriden. Since C++11, you can also do this in the derived class, which would have given you a compiler error for it not being virtual: `void treatLine() override {...}`.

Comment: well, that was the point of my question, I did not know the need to use the word virtual to make my function overriden. I know that now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `treatLine` virtual:

```
virtual void treatLine() {
    std::cout << "treatLine in A" << std::endl;
}
```

That way, the function will be called based on the *runtime* type of the object (called the "dynamic type"), instead of the *compiletime* type (called the "static type") of the object.

Comment: @JerryCoffin haha, fixed :) Bad reading, I thought I would have mentioned static first and dynamic second.

Comment: Making `treatLine` virtual would give calls to `treatLine` an extra overhead and an extra, hidden, member variable (the pointer to the vtable) would be put in all instances of `A` and `B`. Re-defining `void parse()` in `B` the way it is defined in `A` would not, and would most likely give the result Ote is looking for. You should generally only use virtual functions when you have pointer-to-the-base-class pointers which can potentially point to instances of many different classes in the same hierarchy. In this case, the curiously recurring template pattern can also be used to overload `parse`.

Answer (score 0):

Make the treatLine function in A virtual